# Low-res view/filter icons used in stackexchange.com/sites

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, sprites

Page: [stackexchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites)

Imagery is best:

[image: freehand red circling of low-res icons]

[image: blurry, eh?]

It may not look very obvious, but on my screen these are noticibly blurry compared to the rest of the page.

If it makes any difference, I'm using Chrome version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit) on OS X El-Capitan version 10.11.6 (15G1108), Macbook Pro 2015 model.

Comment: The reason is the [sprites on stackexchange.com](https://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/sprites.png?v=8) is a .PNG image (which does not scale), while on other sites it is SVG, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/sprites.svg?v=bb0497e70aa3 for MSE.

Comment: This can also be reproduced by zooming, e.g. at 300% this is what I see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQlV4.png

Comment: @Sha but other PNG sprites are conditionally served larger  and scaled (for high pixel density screens). Not at a computer to check which, but HNQ sidebar favicons definitely are for example. There's no reason these shouldn't be too

Comment: @Cai that's the site logos sprite, which got two versions and it's using some CSS/JS "magic" to serve the proper version according to screen size or resolution. Probably same can be done with the "main" sprites, but since it's already SVG for all sites, guess making it SVG for stackexchange.com would be the easiest way for them.